# Enzime: Wait that context is updated to start execute tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React app that I need to test. It's using the `useContext()` hook to create `Provider` that are using in most of my components. I have a dedicated component to handle a Context (lets say `UserContext` for the example) that look like that:

*UserContext.jsx:*

```js
import React from 'react'

export const UserContext = React.createContext(undefined)

export const UserProvider = (props) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = React.useState(undefined)

  const context = {
    currentUser,
    setCurrentUser,
  }

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={context}>
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

So you can use the `Provider` like that:

```js
import { UserProvider } from './context/UserContext'


<UserProvider>
  { ... }
</UserProvider>
```

Now I need to test a component that use this `UserContext` so let's say `UserModal`:

*UserModal.test.jsx*

```js
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import { UserProvider, UserContext } from '../context/UserContext'
import UserModal from '../components/UserModal'

// D A T A
import exampleUser from '../data/user.json'  // Load user's data from a json file

describe('<UserModal />', () => {
  let wrapper
  const Wrapper = () => {
    const { setCurrentUser } = React.useContext(UserContext)

    React.useEffect(() => {
      // Init UserContext value
      setCurrentUser(exampleUser)
    }, [])

    return (
      <UserProvider>
        <UserModal />
      </UserProvider>
    )
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<Wrapper />)
  })
})
```

Problem is that when `<UserModal />` is mounted inside of the `<UserProvider>`, I get an error that the `currentUser` in the `UserContext` is `undefined`. This error make sense because I call  `setCurrentUser()` when the component is mounted once using `React.useEffect(() => { }, [])`.

So have you an idea how I can `mount()` my `<UserModal />` component inside of a context's provider in the way that the context is not `undefined`?

Answer (score 0):

Your test should look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount } from 'enzyme'
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

import { UserProvider, UserContext } from '../context/UserContext'
import UserModal from '../components/UserModal'

// D A T A
import exampleUser from '../data/user.json'  // Load user's data from a json file

describe('<UserModal />', () => {
  let wrapper
  const Wrapper = () => {
    const { setCurrentUser } = React.useContext(UserContext)

    React.useEffect(() => {
      // Init UserContext value
      setCurrentUser(exampleUser)
    }, [])

    return (
      <UserModal />
    )
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(<UserProvider><Wrapper /></UserProvider>)
  })
})
```

Or see codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-smoke-02n8b?file=/src/App.test.js) - simple test passes.

Note that `UserProvider` wraps `Wrapper` and not is used inside. It's like this because if you are using it inside, there is no `UserContext` to get with `useContext` hook, therefore there is no `setCurrentUser` function.